# building a real time android app with parse android sdk

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, parse-platform, real-time

I want to build an Android app and want its features to be realtime. I will be using parse Android sdk as my mbaas. But its not real time. I once built a snapchat-like app. In the app when someone sends a photo to his/her friends, the receiver has to refresh their feed in order to see his/her message (photo). So i wish to know if it will be possible to use parse cloud (instead of parse android sdk) with nodejs to handle the logic or is there a better option. Thanks.

Comment: you can user ParsePush to send push notifications to the android app and have the app refresh.

Comment: thanks @TomerShemesh  but wont making the app refresh everytime there is a push notification slow or lag the app?

Comment: it shouldnt. i mean the other option is just have your app refresh automatically every minute or something. this would take up the least networking

Comment: also thats how snapchat does it. it sends a push to the device and refreshes when it gets it

Comment: You could use a Cloud messaging platform like Pusher or Realtime.co, they both have Android SDK